# Clustering geolocation data with extra features

Tags: python, kotlin, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, heatmap

I'm trying to build a participatory system for noise monitoring with data collected from mobile clients(Android ones to be more specific, each one with a unique ID). Each client collects data in the following format: [latitude, longitude, noise_value, timestamp]. On top of that, I'm trying to develop a reputation system for those clients to determine how reliable their data is. From what I've read DBSCAN is the most suitable clustering algorithm when it comes to geolocation coordinates, thus I'm using the one implemented in [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html) . Basically, I'm able to group this data in clusters with a radius of 1 or 2 Km. Is it possible to determine the clients that belong to each cluster(I.E: Cluster #1 contains data from clients: #1, #2, #3) and/or the values from it?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the example in the link you have posted. The fit function returns an object that contains an array of labels that represents the cluster each sample belongs to.

```
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 2], [2, 3], [8, 7], [8, 8], [25, 80]])
clustering = DBSCAN(eps=3, min_samples=2).fit(X)
clustering.labels_



array([ 0,  0,  0,  1,  1, -1])
```

If you are using a pandas dataframe you can create a column for the founded clusters.

```
df['cluster'] = clustering.labels_
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! In your example, let's say [1, 2] is the data reported by user #1(which has let's say the value 35 associated to it) and [2, 2] is the data reported by user #2(which has the value 45), is there anyway to get that information as well from dbscan? Like [1,2] belongs to #1 and has the value 35. Or should I implement an algorithm to keep track of each pair of coordinates with their corresponding users and values based on the cluster they belong to?

Comment: Sure, DBSCAN works also with more dimensions, in that case you have something like ([[1, 2, 35], [2, 2, 45], ...).